# Storing JavaScript values forever

Tags: javascript, statistics

So I am making a program that generates 360,000 different values (0s, 1s) and then checks to see if there's anything special about the odds

```
if (zeros < 49.00) {
  console.log("Wow");
} else if (ones < 49.00) {
  console.log("Wow");
} else if (zeros == 50.00 && ones == 50.00) {
  console.log("Perfectly balanced as all things should be");
} else {
  // If there is nothing special in the odds just reload
  location.reload();
}
```

Now this is working perfectly fine, but now I want to store: 
Times the program has run,
Times it's been 50/50,
Times 0s or 1s have been < 49%,

My genius mastermind thought it'd be a great idea to just `zerosMin++` But that didn't work because every time the program runs this value resets. 
But how can I store these "statistics", preferably in another file that doesn't reset?

Comment: Try storing them in local storage

Comment: Utilize localstorage capabilities just don't exceed its quota or if you need it longer-term data-base store it with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variable data in local storage if no backend is involved. Local storage will retain its values until its either manually cleared or the site data is cleared from browser itself. The other available option is to use session storage but that will be gone once you reload or open the same page in new tab.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
  if (localStorage.zerosmin) {
    localStorage.zerosmin) = Number(localStorage.zerosMin) + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.zerosmin = 0;
  }
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  // Some vintage version of IE maybe
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can store variables in [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
2. You can send them to [backend](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp) (post or get request to php, node.js, asp etc.), and read whenever you need them again